# Transfer a 30GB tar file from one remote server to another - restrained by disk space

Tags: files, tar, wget

I have a 38GB "Moodle" tar file that I need to transfer from the old server (Shared hosting), which we can call "Server A" to the new server (Dedicated virtual), or "Server B". I'm with Mediatemple if that helps.

I've already tarballed the directory and used wget to transfer it to server B via SSH, however - it's a puny 100GB package and I'm at 96% disk capacity - meaning I cannot untar the file on server B! Is there any way I can transfer this huge file from Server A to Server B, preserving permissions and with least possible chance file corruption, which will not make me hit the disk limit?

While I have spent quite a while doing this so far, I would be willing to abandon my original plan if someone can offer a better idea - and I would be very grateful!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Don't tar. Use `rsync -av` to preserve permissions while transfering the files. Though like tar, this does not preserve selinux context. Not that I would consider that important though.

Comment: Hi Dennis, thanks for the reply. I don't suppose you could elaborate a bit on how to use the rsync command? Or provide a useful article? Thanks again

Comment: A useful article would be the rsync manpage :) But in a nutshell: if you have ssh access from serverb to servera, run this on serverb: `rsync -av servera:/path/to/files/to/copy/ /path/to/copy/to`

Comment: If you're not sure how to use fundamental commands on the OS that you're using, start with the help facility. On Unix machines, that's often something like `man rsync` or `rsync --help`

Comment: Super - thanks for that. If I'm transferring a directory however, would I not need to change it to add an `-r` to make it recursive? for instance `rsync -arv ssh root@servera.com /path/to/files/to/copy/ /path/to/copy/to` Many thanks again!

Comment: `-a` implies `-r` (and many more flags people kept forgetting until `-a` was added as "these are the useful flags for making backups")

Comment: Super - worked like a charm. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Please edit answer instead of prolongating comments: You may make this more readable ;-)

Comment: You may have to use `--numeric-ids` option to ensure owner and groups won't change

Comment: i suggest using rsync over ssh if You have ssh access on both servers. Also You may have sensitive info like db content. `rsync -rav -e ssh user@server:/var/www/prod/ /var/cache/www`

Comment: If security is not a problem (I mean you trust the network between the two machines) nc is also an option. On the server:
tar -zc source | nc -l 1313 
On the client:
nc SERVER_IP 1313 | tar -zx

Answer (score 12):

You probably want to buy more disk space, but assuming you don't, you could...

pipe the tarball around rather than downloading it.

```
newserver#  ssh olduser@oldserver "cat /path/to/tarball" | tar xf -
```

---

or if you don't have SSH access to your old server

```
newserver# wget -O - http://oldserver/path/to/tarball | tar xf -
```

---

or [use rsync like Dennis said](https://serverfault.com/a/526343/32986).

Be creative. There are other solutions I'm not mentioning.

Comment: You may have to use `--numeric-owner` option before making tarball to ensure owner and groups won't change. `ssh ouser@oserver tar -zcplC /src_path --numeric-owner . | tar -zxpC /dst_path `

Comment: @F.Hauri `--numeric-owner` can have (potentially serious) unintended consequences if the UID/GID scheme differs between the two machines. This is usually not an issue in the internal environment, but moving from "shared hosting" to "dedicated virtual" this could cause problems. You should expect to have to fix ownership on the new server if using `tar`, `cpio`, and possibly even `rsync`.

Comment: Yes, you're right but, not knowing about this kind of option could have (same) border effect too. Best of all: know what you're doing and... rtfm;-)

Comment: ... some interesting way (filters) to use (or not) to *be creative*: `nc` òr `openssl`, `sed`, `gpg`, `uuencode` and `mail` (with care;) , `enscript` + `lpr` + *[avian carriers] (http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_over_Avian_Carriers)* + `scan` + `ocr`... But there are even more...